# JS through InvokeScript

Tags: c#, .net, browser, webbrowser-control

How to perform JS code:

```
callbacks [0] (this, {"__title": null});
```

through ->

```
wb.Document.InvokeScript();
```

Or maybe there is still what ways?

Comment: InvokeScript lets you call js functions, not random script fragments.

Comment: How to call this piece of code?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `eval` JS function like this :

```
var javascript = "[insert the JS code you want to perform]"

wb.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { javascript });
```

However beware that if you want to port your software on windows 8 as an appstore application, the `WebView` control (which replaces the `WebBrowser`) can't call the `eval` function (nor the `alert` function, and I forgot the last one but you can find more doc on the internet).

Comment: var javascript = "[callbacks[0](this, {"__title":null});]"; The compiler generates an error, Required ";" but where is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks problem solved!!!**

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.text = "function MyJsCode() {callbacks [0] (this, {"__title": null});}";
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("MyJsCode");
```